# How to filter rows in R based on the number of variables within a column?

Tags: r

[image]

I would like to filter out the rows of majors that do not have at least 10 people taking the major. For example, in the photo there are only 3 people majoring in zoology, so I would like to filter out all zoology majors. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` and `filter` from `dplyr` as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ciptitle) %>%
  filter(n()>=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset`:

```
subset(df, grepl("ZOOLOGY", ciptitle))
```

Or the `dplyr` way:

```
dplyr::filter(df, grepl("ZOOLOGY", ciptitle))
```

Comment: I would like to do this for all majors that do not have at least 10 people taking the major.

Comment: @VivianneTu In that case I recommend grouping by `ciptitle`; any further data manipulation is then applied on the group level (as @MKR demonstrates in his answer).